# Configured Pymodbus baudrate different from /dev/ttySX

Tags: tty, serial-port, python3

I am programming a modbus client to read a sensor. I have a code that works correctly on Windows (with multiple baudrates). However, when running it on Linux the baudrate is incorrect. I am using the `pymodbus==3.1.0`.

I tried to make a minimal working example but then the baudrate is set correctly. The only difference between this code and the one the device is that `GuiProcess` is running a python tkiner gui which allows selection of device.

```
from pymodbus.pdu import ModbusRequest
from pymodbus.client import ModbusSerialClient
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer
from pymodbus.exceptions import ModbusIOException
import time
import multiprocessing

MODUBS_REGISTER_READ_BLOCK = 100

# Communication process 
def COMProcess():
    client = ModbusSerialClient(
            method = 'rtu'
            ,port= "/dev/ttyS0"
            ,baudrate=19200
            ,parity = 'N'
            ,stopbits=1
            ,bytesize=8
            ,timeout=0.1
            ,RetryOnEmpty = True
            ,RetryOnInvalid = True
        )

    connection = client.connect()
    time.sleep(2)

    while(1):
        rr = client.read_holding_registers(0 ,MODUBS_REGISTER_READ_BLOCK,slave=0x12)
        time.sleep(1)

    client.close()

# Communication process 
def GuiProcess():
    while(1):
        time.sleep(1)
        # In the real scenario a tkinter gui is running here
        print("elapsed 1 sec")

# Start multiple thread, one for GUI and another for COM
p1 =  multiprocessing.Process(target= COMProcess )
p2 =  multiprocessing.Process(target= GuiProcess )

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

In the real device if I print the client information it seems that it is correctly configured. However the messages are send physically at 9600 bauds (measured with osciloscope).

```
ModbusSerialClient(<pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer.ModbusRtuFramer object at 0x7fc3749c6f20> baud[19200])
```

Any ideas of what can cause this type of misaligment between `pymodbus` serial client and the `/dev/ttyS0` and how can I force a specific baudrate?

Comment: Perhaps the gui part is opening an re-initialising each port. Try starting it first, adding a `time.sleep(5)` or similar before starting the com part. You can `strace -f -o logfile` in front of your program to see who is doing what calls on the devices.